# Ubuntu 12.04 i have removed lightdm

Tags: 12.04, ati, lightdm

My problem began when I have restarted my laptop after I have installed a new GUI, I have Ubuntu 12.04 with ATI mobility HD 5470, but all was fine and working good. On my Ultimate Edition 3.4 I have Google-d how to fix that and someone suggested that :

`sudo apt-get remove lightdm then sudo apt-get install lightdm`

would solve the problem, but my problem was I only could apply `sudo apt-get remove lightdm`, then it wont take the install lightdm order, and I ended up with only a black screen after I boot and choose Ubuntu from my dual OS booting (I have Linux and win7), I cant even switch or see tty. I have worked on my Ubuntu a lot and don't want just reinstall it again and lose all I have built in it before.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get update`

Comment: In the future please be more specific. For example, "new GUI" and "how to fix that" are not clear enough as to what you're talking about. We can't effectively help you without these details.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to press CMD-ALT-F1 to get to a console. Type your username and password, then run `sudo apt-get install lightdm`. Then, just in case, run `sudo service lightdm start`. Press CMD-ALT-F7 to get to the login screen.